# Cycles and other addons dont work anymore

Tags: add-on, installation

After i downloaded Blender 2.79b I got some problems...
i tried to install Flip Fluid. But I got tons of errors.

After that Cycles has stopped working. I also got an error message after I tried to activate it again in the User Preferences.

I deleted 2.79b and got back to 2.79. 
But still the same error.

I also tried to install a older graphic driver (installed the newest at the same time i downloaded 2.79b).

I also set blender back to the factory settings. But still nothing changed.

I realy dont know what do to anymore.. hopefully one of you guys got an idea =)

ps. there also pops up an error message if I try to open "Release log" "blender store" ect.

thanks for your help and sorry my english x)

---

Win 7 / 64 Bit

Nvidia Geforce GTX 770

[image: Error after trying to select cycles addon]

Comment: My guess is you've stuffed up your user addons folder.  Type `bpy.utils.script_paths('addons')` <return> into the python console. You will see a list of folders.  The one in your user folder, the result of this command `bpy.utils.script_path_user()` is your user addons folder.  Try renaming it temporarilly from `addons` to `addons_bup` and restart blender.  (You will not have your user installed addons)  If this removes the error above [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/110287/edit) your question, or comment and can proceed from there.

Comment: thanks for your help. But if i type in that command i get also an error. Isnt it weird that the reinstall did not fix the problem ?

Comment: The reinstall doesn't touch your user files. [See this link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) which details addon paths. Search your system for "addons" folders. Rename the one that is in a user path. It's my guess that the files from flip fluid and in particular `__init__.py` have been installed incorrectly in this folder. (Rather than in a folder within the addon folder)  [Do you have a link to the flip fluid addon.?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/110287/edit)

Comment: ... if that addon (or another) has a module named "types" and it has been mistakenly installed in your addons file then it will cause an error similar to the one you are getting.

Comment: Good one, write up an answer it may help someone else. Could try cleaning addons folder by removing files using  modification times.