# I can't change my interaction, frame rate, render present, unit presents

Tags: frame-rate

[image][image]

At first I was trying to change my frame rate but I was unable to do so. Then I tried to change my interaction and again I couldn't when I click on the blender(default) this report:error comes up. Please help

Comment: [Possibly related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110287/cycles-and-other-addons-dont-work-anymore#comment194348_110287)

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/